# visibility of extern symbol and portability

Tags: c++, linker, extern

I'm trying to make a special .cpp file, which would have a `const char* version`, containing package version, which would then after compilation be linked both to a library and executables in the package. The library and executables reference it as an `extern` symbol, like this:

version.cpp

```
const char* version=VERSION_STRING;
```

version.h

```
extern const char* version;
```

The codes in library and executables have

```
#include "version.h"
```

Now, the problem is that the executables have to ask the library of library version, but as the symbol is `extern`, names of its instances collide, and the result is that even if library version is different, the executable thinks it's the same.

I've tried avoiding this with `-fvisibility=hidden` gcc option, or corresponding `__attribute__` (in fact, its wrapper in glib: `G_GNUC_INTERNAL`), and it works, but what bothers me is that it's not at all portable, namely, I'm not sure how this would work in Windows.

So the question is: what is a cleaner way to avoid too much recompilation when changing version and still not have externally-visible (outside of given binary) version symbol, not sacrificing portability?

Answer (score 2):

Either:

- the executables have to "ask" the library for the version (in which case the symbol should *not* be extern, and you the library should just provide some `const char *lib_get_version()` function)
- or the symbol should be extern and visible directly to the executable, in which case it should *only* be provided by the library. That is, version.cpp would be linked into the library but not the executable, so the library provides the symbol to the final executable.

The first option is probably the simplest and most portable.

---

For two versions, which may not be the same:

1. create two separate files, say `lib_version.cpp` and `bin_version.cpp`, exporting `const char *get_lib_version()` and `const char *get_bin_version()` respectively
2. compile the first cpp file into the lib, and the second into the bin.
3. if the *thing being versioned* is the same, say if the bin and lib have different versions of some API, create a private header used by both cpp files

   ```
   // header_impl.h
   #define VERSION_STRING "1.2.3"

   // lib_version.h
   const char *get_lib_version();

   // lib_version.cpp (linked only in lib)
   #include <version_impl.h>
   const char *get_lib_version() { return VERSION_STRING; }

   // bin_version.h
   const char *get_bin_version();

   // bin_version.cpp (linked only in bin)
   #include <version_impl.h>
   const char *get_bin_version() { return VERSION_STRING; }
   ```

   Now, both the lib and bin contain a shapshot of the version, from the version_impl header, at the time they were compiled. You can get both values with no linker collision.

Comment: The executable and library may have different versions and must report both correctly, this is the core of the problem.

Comment: Ah, your question said "version", singular.

Answer (score 0):

to solve versioning issue like this in cross compiling code usually you have the following approach:

```
- both the library and app have their own .cpp file.
 - the library includes a getLibVersion() function in the API to get the library version.
 - the app has access to this getLibVersion() and either calls it to build a larger string containing both lib and app string(eg. 16bit for app, 16 bit for lib giving a 32 bit string) or provides a wrapper for this function which can be called from the app API.
```

bottom line - there are two version.cpp files (lib+app) - you do have to rebuild the app in case the lib version changes - and the app either provides functionality in it's API to get the versions separately or concatenated.

Hope this helps.